# Install ASE in opensuse leap 42.3

Tags: opensuse

I am trying to install python-ase. I have installed python using Yast, but when I search python-ase it is not found. How can I install ase?

Comment: Have you even tried to write this question in a web search engine?

Comment: Can you display your code or describe a bit more your question please?